# Convert dataframe to dictionary with list as values

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this:

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| case1 | % | case description1 |
| case2 | ab | case description2 |
| case3 | gh | case description3 |
| case4 | sg | case description4 |

I want to convert this df to a dictionary, so I want it to look like this:

```
{case1:['%','casedescription1'],case2:['ab','case description2'],case3:['gh','case description3], case4:['sg','case description4']}
```

I want to later use this dict to update values into a table in our sqldb
using this function:

```py
def update_units(source_dictionary,tag_list):
    for ID in id_list:
      key=ID
      value1=(source_dictionary[ID][1] if ID in source_dictionary else None)
      value2=(source_dictionary[ID][2] if ID in source_dictionary else None)
      
      session.query(table1).filter(table1.Id == key).update(
                {
                    "A": value1,
                    "B": value2
                }
            )
    session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first create an `array` from columns A and B. Then, `collect` into a dictionary comprehension.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('case1', '%', 'case description1'),
     ('case2', 'ab', 'case description2'),
     ('case3', 'gh', 'case description3'),
     ('case4', 'sg', 'case description4')],
    ['ID', 'A', 'B'])

df = df.select('ID', F.array('A', 'B'))
dic = {k: v for k, v in df.collect()}

print(dic)
# {'case1': ['%', 'case description1'], 'case2': ['ab', 'case description2'], 'case3': ['gh', 'case description3'], 'case4': ['sg', 'case description4']}
```